# PowerBI with DocumentDB connector

Tags: azure, powerbi, azure-cosmosdb

We are having issues with PowerBI DocumentDB connector - it occasionally fails with "Request rate is large" error. The things is that it happens even on maximal available performance level (S3) for DocumentDB.

```
Expression.Error: The field 'Documents' of the record wasn't found.
Details:
    code=429
    message=Message: {"Errors":["Request rate is large"]}
ActivityId: 432e8f14-05f2-44db-b9fe-c28b8e1de766, Request URI: /apps/e842e452-2347-4a8e-8588-2f5f8b4803ad/services/7bdb37d7-c5a5-4fdd-b547-fcb9a60e7372/partitions/f5cabdb0-442d-473b-893d-e2d0a79cf941/replicas/131117893523391414p
```

(the error above does not look accurate by the way, there is no "Documents" field referenced anywhere - what does matter is "underlying" error with request rate)

Looks like PowerBI DocumentDB connector does not have any retry policies to deal with such kind of issues and it makes its usage effective impossible.

Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Not exactly sure of issue, but S3 is not maximum perf level. If you switch to `Standard`, you may scale from 400 RU to 10000 RU. S3 is 2500 RU.

Comment: @DavidMakogon, thanks - I see the new pricing tiers now. It would be $600 monthly, just because PowerBI developers did not incorporate appropriate retry polices... I would like to figure out cheaper solution.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't suggesting creating a max-performance collection. I was merely letting you know, so that you can at least attempt bumping up the perf a bit to see if the error goes away (and by shifting to Standard, this would allow you to experiment this way). It could be that you're running close to the S3 threshold with only occasional bursts above it. Just offering you an option to help diagnose, is all.

Comment: @DavidMakogon, I understand and really appreciate your answer -- I will definitely check it out!

Comment: For what it's worth, the PowerBI DocumentDB connector retries up to two times, respecting the x-ms-retry-after-ms header in the 429 response. If there's another 429 on the third attempt, it comes out back to you.

Comment: @CurtHagenlocher, thanks, Curt for your internal (?) insights! Looks like it's not enough to make the whole thing resilient...

Comment: I'll update the retry count to 9 for the next release.